# How to import the external JS with callback function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google API, based on their link I have to put the following script in the HTML file

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=callback"></script>
```

The custom callback function is being loaded after the client.js is loaded successfully.

```
function callback() {
  var ROOT = 'https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api';
  gapi.client.load('your_api_name', 'v1', function() {
    doSomethingAfterLoading();
  }, ROOT);
}
```

I would like to

1. Separate HTML with JS file
2. I downloaded the client.js file and put it in my local repo. But for reducing web request I would like to concat the client.js with other JS file. But I have no idea how to load the content with the concatenated JS file with the callback is being called

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for javascript only solution:

```
var sScriptSrc = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=callback"
loadScript(sScriptSrc);

function loadScript(sScriptSrc) {
    var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
    var oScript = document.createElement('script');
    oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    oScript.src = sScriptSrc;
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
    oScript.onload = loadedCallback();
}

function loadedCallback() {
    alert("WoHooo I am loaded");
}
```

See it running here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/24x1jw6d/3/)

**EDIT**

Let me do some refining, if I understand correctly what you want to achieve:

I made a simple main html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    PAGE BODY
</body>
</html>
```

Which is loading `client.js`

client.js contains:

```
// you can call this function with
//     param1: src of the script to load
//     param2: function name to be executed once the load is finished 
function loadScript(sScriptSrc, loadedCallback) {
    var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
    var oScript = document.createElement('script');
    oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    oScript.src = sScriptSrc;
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
    oScript.onload = loadedCallback;
}

// let's load the Google API js and run function GoggleApiLoaded once it is done.
loadScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", GoggleApiLoaded);

function GoggleApiLoaded() {
    alert("WoHooo Google API js loaded");
}
```

Of course, instead of `GoggleApiLoaded` example function you could run a method which start the loading of different js and the callback of that one could load a next one and so on...

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Actually the callback function will be executed (and will be executed by client.js after it is loaded, not by writing our own function. I tried to put my own code (api.client.load) inside the callback function but it does't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a nice method for this. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

```
jQuery.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", function() {
        console.log("hello");
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part. But the ultimate goal is to concat the client.js into one big JS file. If that is the case how could I use the getScript function? Thanks

Comment: Also I tried the jQuery function method. The function within the callback (gapi.client.load) is undefined

Comment: to use this jquery facility, you will have to load it before. So, the jquery lib file can not be merged in your "big js file".

Comment: Gael, JQuery is working. The non-functioning part is the function within the callback (api.client.load) which is defined in the client.js file.

Comment: Short but fantastic answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be compatible with IE, including IE 9, you can use this async JS file loader & callback:

```
function loadAsync(src, callback){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src; 
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    if(callback != null){
        if (script.readyState) { // IE, incl. IE9
            script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script.onload = function() { // Other browsers
                callback();
            };
        }
    }
    a=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    a.parentNode.insertBefore(script,a);
}

loadAsync("https://www.example.com/script.js", callbackFunction);

function callbackFunction() {
    console.log('Callback function run');
}
```

Comment: According to http://kangax.github.io/jstests/script-element-onload-attribute-support/ IE9 seems to support script.onload