# How to wait for PyScript to be fully initialised (environment included)?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, pyscript

Good morning,

I would like to wait for a message (logged to my browser's console by a script I imported in my HTML  tag) to be logged and then do an action in JavaScript.

For example, I'd like to wait for "ABCD:READY" to be printed in the console to use a function called finallyStart().

Is it possible ?

I thought I only needed to read the content of stdout to do this, but it looks like browsers don't call their console output stdout...

I also tried to find an answer in stackoverflow, but none of the posts I found were similar to the one I'm currently writing.

I'm a novice when it comes to JS in browsers (I've only used NodeJS for back-end), so thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: You could overwrite `console.log`, but you really shouldn't. Make the script that you are importing fire a proper event, or accept a callback.

Comment: If I shouldn't, then I woun't ! I'm trying to build a well-made website. I can't modify the script I'm importing (it's pyScript). I tried using addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback), but it stops when pyScript finishes loading the "main tools", so before downloading the environment (matplotlib, sklearn...). At the end of all the downloads, the script logs "[pyscript/main] PyScript page fully initialized".
Is there a better parameter for addEventListener to make it wait for absolutely everything to finish ?

Comment: Thanks, you should [edit] your question (esp the title) to describe what you actually want to achieve, whether by hooking on `console.log` or by some better way. Why do you think modifying pyscript is not possible?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, by the way !
Now that you say it, I guess what we import is pyscript's code, so maybe it can be modified. I'll go read something about this. About the title, what do you think about "How to wait for a log (from an external script) in Chrome's console to be displayed ?" ?
P.S. : I wrote woun't instead of won't. It looks like I'm developing some kind of weird accent even when I'm writing !

Comment: No, the title should be something like "How to wait for PyScript to be fully initialised?". Also, what kind of application are you trying to build, and what do you want your code to do when PyScript is initialised?

Comment: From a quick skimming of https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript, you might be looking for a plugin or a hook or something, but these don't seem well-documented. Possibly also relevant: [page lifecycle](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/763)

Comment: Thanks ! I made a custom loading animation (pyscript's default animation is not very aesthetic), and I simply wanted to stop displaying that custom animation from the page once everything is fully loaded.
I've read the doc, and I didn't find an answer in it.
I'll try importing pyscript another way, following this idea : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858274/how-to-import-the-external-js-with-callback-function

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and eventually came up with this hacky but working solution.

First create a dummy element in your html.

```
<div hidden id="start"></div>
```

Make an event for that element call a function in your js script.

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = main;
```

Then trigger that event manually from your python script.

```
from pyscript import Element
Element("start").element.click()
```

No python code can execute until pyscript has finished initializing, so this seems like a reliable strategy. It would be even better if you could call the `main()` function directly from your python script, but i didn't have the patience to figure that out.

p.s. For some reason it takes a few seconds after pyscript has officially initialized for the code to kick off (at least in my test). I have no idea what's happening during that time, though i suppose it doesn't make a big difference to the already hefty build time.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer. About your post-scriptum : that's a big problem for me because I use py-repl elements, and they can't be used until everything is loaded (which makes my website slow and the loading animation's duration almost random)… I didn't find anything about this in the doc, but I guess it's some kind of asynchronous behavior. I don't have time to do it right now, but I'll let you know if I (cleanly) fix this problem.